# Kotlin – Why parameter values have to be passed in sub classes?

Tags: class, kotlin, subclass, subclassing

My code:

```
open class Club(name: String, country: String)

class FemaleClub(): Club()

var femaleClub = FemaleClub("Blue", "Australia")
```

Why is the above code not possible?

Why does it have the error

> no value passed for parameter name

and

> no value passed for parameter country

in my subclass? The values are set when I initiate `femaleClub`.

Comment: If the body of your class is empty you can omit the brackets {}, makes the code shorter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example parent class `Club` has **primary constructor** which is, by language specification, must be called either from **secondary constructors** of the same class or **primary constructor** of subclasses to initialize parameters defined in **primary constructor**. If you don't want to call a **primary constructor** of a parent class from subclasses you have a couple of options:

1. Set default values to parameters of **primary constructor**:

   ```
   open class Club(name: String = "DefaultName", country: String = "Country") {
   }
   ```

   In this case you will not be able to call **primary constructor** with params:

   ```
   // this is not possible
   var femaleClub = FemaleClub("Blue", "Australia")
   ```
2. Create **secondary constructor** in parent class which calls **primary constructor**:

   ```
   open class Club(name: String, country: String) {

       constructor(): this("Name", "Country")
   }
   ```

   But also you won't be able to call `FemaleClub("Blue", "Australia")`.

To be able to call constructor with parameters of a subclass `FemaleClub("Blue", "Australia")` you need explicitly define them in **primary constructor** of the subclass and call parent's primary constructor, i.e.:

```
class FemaleClub(name: String, country: String): Club(name, country) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code:

- `FemaleClub` does not have a constructor which accepts two arguments, even if the base class has one.
- The primary constructor of the inherited class should call the primary constructor of the base class. Because your base class accepts two non-nullable arguments, you have to provide them to it, otherwise your code wont compile.

These issues can be fixed in the following way:

```
class FemaleClub(name: String, country: String): Club(name, country) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

About Kotlin classes and inheritance, read here [Classes and Inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) and here [Kotlin Inheritance](https://www.journaldev.com/19705/kotlin-inheritance).

You can use at least four approaches to get what you want:

**First approach (`default values`):**

```
open class Club(var name: String = "Blue", var country: String = "Australia") {  }

public class FemaleClub(): Club() {  }

fun main() { 
    var femaleClub = FemaleClub()
    println("RESULT: ${femaleClub.country}")
}

// RESULT: Australia
```

**Second approach (`passing values`):**

```
open class Club(var name: String, var country: String) {  }

class FemaleClub(): Club("Green", "NZ") {  }

fun main() {
    var femaleClub = FemaleClub()
    println("RESULT: ${femaleClub.country}")
}

// RESULT: NZ
```

**Third approach (`init block`):**

```
open class Club(name: String, country: String) {  

    var name: String = "Blue"
    var country: String = "Australia"

    init {
        this.name = name
        this.country = country 
    }
}

class FemaleClub(): Club("Green", "NZ") {  }

fun main() {
    var femaleClub = FemaleClub()
    println("RESULT: ${femaleClub.country}")
}

// RESULT: NZ
```

**Fourth approach (`class sec.constructor`):**

```
open class Club {  

    var name: String
    var country: String

    constructor(name: String = "Blue", country: String = "Australia") {
        this.name = name
        this.country = country
    }
}

class FemaleClub(): Club() {  }

fun main() {
    var femaleClub = FemaleClub()
    println("RESULT: ${femaleClub.country}")
}

// RESULT: Australia
```

Comment: Ok, I won't use them.

Comment: thx man, makes answers more pleasent to read. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

In `FemaleClub` you are not specifying what should be passed to `Club` as its 2 `String` arguments, `name` and `country`.

And you are not specifying anywhere that `FemaleClub` takes 2 strings as constructor arguments, so the last line wont work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the constructor (primary/secondary) from the class you want to inherit from.

`Club` only has one constructor, the primary constructor. It takes two strings as parameters. `Club` does not have an empty constructor.

So, it cannot be invoked as `Club()`.

I would propose two changes.

**1) Make `name` and `country` of `Club` properties**

```
open class Club(name: String, country: String)
```

**2) Declare parameters in `FemaleClub`'s primary constructor**

Since you want to be able to specify values for `name` and `country` when you instantiate `FemaleClub` it would be a good idea to give the primary constructor of `FemaleClub` `name` and `country` as parameters.

Additionally I would recommend using named parameters when passing on the values, since you can easily mix up the two strings (resulting in passing name as country and country as name.

```
class FemaleClub(name: String, country: String): Club(name = name, country = country)
```